# why 2 stacks are so effective for post-order transverses

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, postorder

So I am familiar with postorder traversing:

L -> R -> P (Left to Right to Parent).

I saw a code that could perform a postorder traversal quite elegantly using 2 stacks:

```
public void postOrderTransverse(Node r){
    if(r == null){return;}
    Stack<Node> s = new Stack<Node>();
    Stack<Node> reverser = new Stack<Node>();
    s.push(r);
    while(!s.isEmpty()){
        Node temp = s.pop();
        reverser.push(temp);
        if (temp.left != null){
            s.push(temp.left);}
        if(temp.right != null){
            s.push(temp.right);}
    }
    while(!reverser.empty()){
        System.out.print(reverser.peek());
        reverser.pop();
    }
}
```

(via http://articles.leetcode.com/binary-tree-post-order-traversal/)

where essentially, one Stack just reverses the other. I am just very curious about how this works. I have a hypothesis that Stack s accepts input so that the output would be something like P -> R -> L, and it just passes that onto Stack reverser which spits out L -> R .-> P since it's Last In First Out.

However, just trying to think through the processes of this algorithm, I'm struggling to understand how and why Stack s takes its input the way it does. Hoping I could get some insight on here! Thanks :)

Comment: It is doing a pre-order traversal using the first stack, and pushing the results onto the second stack, then popping that stack, which gives you a post-order traversal just by reversing the results.

Comment: @EJP, it is not doing pre-order traversal, as it traverses right node first. In fact this is a loop version of a recursive post-order traversal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you provided is simply a loop version of the corresponding recursive solution:

```
public void postOrderTraverseRecursive(Node r){
    if(r == null){return;}

    if (r.left != null){
        postOrderTraverseRecursive(r.left);}
    if(r.right != null){
        postOrderTraverseRecursive(r.right);}

    System.out.print(r);
}
```

In order to transform recursion to a loop we need to [reverse the order of the statements execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/159777/3707125). We will use one stack to maintain recursion invocations, and one to maintain output of the recursion (i.e. `System.out.print` statement arguments).

Your code with more meaningful variable names and explanation:

```
public void postOrderTraverse(Node root){
    if(root == null){return;}
    Stack<Node> recursionStack = new Stack<Node>();
    Stack<Node> printStack = new Stack<Node>();
    recursionStack.push(root);
    while(!recursionStack.isEmpty()){
        Node node = recursionStack.pop();
        /* Recursion iteration start */
        // According to the recursion we should process left->right->node.
        // Considering that in the loop version we have to reverse the order of invocations,
        // we are processing node->right->left
        printStack.push(node); // node is added to printStack immediately
        // left is added to recursionStack first, but because
        // of the FILO nature of the stack it will be processed last
        if (node.left != null){
            recursionStack.push(node.left);}
        // right is added to recursionStack last, but because
        // of the FILO nature of the stack it will be processed first
        if(node.right != null){
            recursionStack.push(node.right);}
        /* Recursion iteration end */
    }
    // We've processed all the input and now we have reversed
    // history of the prints, processing them in reverse order
    // to receive the actual one
    while(!printStack.empty()){
        System.out.print(printStack.peek());
        printStack.pop();
    }
}
```